# how to pass and use the variables passed through header() in php from 1 file to another

Tags: php

I have an array of variables in "$variables" and it contains data such as :-

```
$variables['firstname'] = "Sachin"; (say the user filled in these)
$variables['lastname'] = "Tendulkar";
$variables['firstname'] = "SachinTendulkar";
```

Now, after validation on the same page, I use :-

```
header("Location:http://localhost/PhpSample/target.php");
```

to redirect the user to another page "target.php". What would be the syntax in "header()" function to pass the values of the array $variables to "target.php" file and use those values in "target.php" file to display the user what they entered ?

Code of target.php

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo "Firstname:" .; //Here what needs to be written after . and before ; to use the values passed from the other file
echo "<br>";
echo "Lastname:" .;
echo '<br>';
echo "Username:" .;
echo '<br>';
?>
```

I read somewhere that we have to use $_GET['firstname'] in "target.php" to use those values. If it is correct then is that not safe because $_GET should not be used for sensitive information such as username,password etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to pass array through `header()`, use `http_build_query`:

```
header("Location:http://localhost/PhpSample/target.php?vals=" . http_build_query($arr));
```

Note that a redirect by its nature cannot do a POST. it will result in a new GET request, meaning you have to pass data in the URL. If you have a very large url, you're almost guaranteed to lose most of it, as URLs have length limits.

However, if it's a short one, you can also try something like:

```
header("Location:http://localhost/PhpSample/target.php?vals=" . urlencode(serialize($variables)));
```

You can access the array values in *target.php* file as:

```
$Values= unserialize(urldecode($_GET['vals']));
echo "<h2>Your Input</h2>";
foreach($Values as $key => $value) {
  echo $key." : ".$value."<br>";
}
```

Otherwise

```
<?php
$Values= unserialize(urldecode($_GET['vals']));
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo "Firstname:" .$Values['firstname']; //Here what needs to be written after . and before ; to use the values passed from the other file
echo "<br>";
echo "Lastname:" .$Values['lastname'];
echo '<br>';
echo "Username:" .$Values['username'];
echo '<br>';
?>
```

Comment: And how do I access each individual value of the array $variables in "target.php" to display the output to the user with the help of "target.php" in my code?

Comment: Thanks it works,but I wanted to show the appropriate ans at the o/p  meaning in "target.php" :- <?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo "Firstname:" .; //Here what needs to be written after . and before ; to use the values passed from the other file
echo "<br>";
echo "Lastname:" .;
echo '<br>';
echo "Username:" .;
echo '<br>';
?>

Comment: @sachintendulkar..Check my updated answer. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks it works, it shows the output as firstname=Sachinlastname=Tendulkarusername=SachinTendulkar i.e in the url form,but I wanted to show the appropriate ans at the o/p ,meaning in "target.php" :- <?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo "Firstname:" .; //Here what needs to be written after . and before ; to use the values passed from the other file
echo "<br>";
echo "Lastname:" .;
echo '<br>';
echo "Username:" .;
echo '<br>';
?> i.e what do I write next to the dot of the code echo "Username:" .; ???

Comment: Your ans is good but I wanted to show next to the echo statements

Comment: @sachintendulkar..I am not getting you. Can you make it as a html and show me? Before please check my answer once more. I am not sure whether you are checking my updated one or not.

Comment: M extremely thankful for your time and code,but it is working partially

Comment: Show me the figure of how you exactly need it

Comment: This is the answer I get on "target.php" :-firstname=Sachinlastname=Tendulkarusername=SachinTendulkar          Your Input:
Firstname:
Lastname:
Username:                                                           So I get the ans at the top but not next to Firstname: Lastname: and Username:

Comment: Extremely Sorry , I am getting the ans. Thank You and sorry for the trouble. I saw your updated ans later

Comment: There is just one change to the code :- It is                           header("Location:http://localhost/PhpSample/target.php?vals=" . urlencode(serialize($variables))); and not url_encode

Answer (score 2):

for example you pass variable name : "flagtype" and its value="network"

write header location code from where you want to pass ,

```
 header("location:anotherfilename.php?flagtype=network&variable2=value2");
```

syntax :

```
header("location:anotherfilename.php?variablename=valuename&variablename2=value2");
```

Answer (score 1):

What i have done in the past to get a variable to another page is to set the variable to a `$_SESSION` variable.
This will assign the variable to be accessed by any page.

Remember to start the session before using any $_SESSION variables:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['userData'] = $variables;
```

userData is a name given to the Sessionsit can be named anything, and this name is what you will use to retrieve that same Session.  [PHP Manual on $_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

```
$userDataFromValidation = $_SESSION['userData'];
```

This way your avoiding any Get request which the user could use to perform an XSS.

Comment: So what would be the header() function syntax in the first file and how do I access each individual value of the array $variables in "target.php" to display the output to the user with the help of "target.php"?

Comment: You leave the header function alone it is already doing its job by redirecting the user.

You access the variable by using its keys

`echo 'Firstname: ' . $userDataFromValidation['Firstname'];`

Comment: I have included the following code of lines in both the files :-          $GLOBALS['userData'] = $variables; and $userDataFromValidation = $GLOBALS['userData']; and used echo 'Firstname: ' . $userDataFromValidation['firstname']; But it does not show the output

Comment: You include the first line of code on your validation page  and the second line on the target page.  Not both on both pages

Comment: @DirtyRedz I guess you messed up globals not with $_SERVER, but with $_COOKIE or $_SESSION. If so, please, edit your answer.

Comment: Answer Updated my apologies got those names mixed up. P.S. using sessions is more secure then using Get Request, as get request are easily changed by a user. However Session data can be spoofed its much more difficult but usually not effected by your average user. unlike Get Request which an any day user could accidently change.  Also Get Request can be bookmarked by the user and is not something you want done on form $_POST data or LOGIN specific data.

Comment: I wanted to use without sessions or cookies. I just wanted to use header() and m not getting the right ans with your code above

Comment: If your not getting the code to work your doing something wrong, post your entire code block. Also why do you want to use get our post request, they can't be trusted. If you would explain your needs in more detail. More detailed help could be given

Comment: You do understand the difference between sessions and cookies right?

Comment: My code is very very big n I will not be able to paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP Location field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) accepts URLs in general format, so you can add GET parameters to it:

```
 header('Location: http://domain.com/path/to/file/?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2');
```

Both POST and GET parameters are very easily to be modified and are not secure if you are not using SSL or similar encryption methods. If you need to pass some sensitive information, use [session](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['parameter'] = 'value';
```

Cookies are, in general, not secure too.